# Statistical significance test for 5-fold cross validation on a single dataset

Tags: neural-networks, statistical-significance, cross-validation, wilcoxon-signed-rank, friedman-test

I have used stratified 5-fold cross validation to generate five data folds to compare several (N) deep learning models on a single dataset. Now, I have the fold-wise test accuracies for all of the models as shown below:

```
Algo Fold Accuracy
1   fold1   83.15
1   fold2   83.28
1   fold3   83.53
1   fold4   85.93
1   fold5   86.23
2   fold1   81.18
2   fold2   82.09
2   fold3   80.54
2   fold4   83.23
2   fold5   83.83
3   fold1   81.74
3   fold2   84.18
3   fold3   83.83
3   fold4   84.13
3   fold5   86.83
-----------------
```

Which statistical test is suitable for assessing the difference among model performances? I've used Friedman test followed by a post-hoc analysis based on the Wilcoxon-Holm method as described [here](https://github.com/hfawaz/cd-diagram) but it shows "Sample size too small for normal approximation." warning and there is no significant difference among all the models.

Is it beneficial to do a pairwise McNemar's test after summing up all the contingency metrics from different folds, I mean Cochran's Q test followed by McNemar?
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could find the average accuracy for each algorithm, but for a significance test you will need to know the number of observations in the validation sets.

Comment: @Henry I have access to the underlying fold-wise predictions. Do you think it's beneficial to do a pairwise McNemar's test after summing up all the contingency metrics, I mean Cochran's Q test followed by McNemar?